# Creating startup program for all users 12.04 - only working for 1 user

Tags: 12.04, multiple-users

In ubuntu 12.04 LTS desktop, I'm trying to have chromium start up automatically for all users upon login.
I did the following:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
```

What happens is that chromium only starts up for user that created the directory, and not any other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all users, try with:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart
```

or with:

```
for user in /home/*; do sudo cp /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop $user/.config/autostart/; done
```

The tilde character (`~`) refers to your home directory, so `~` it's equivalent with `/home/your_username`, which mean that you created that startup program only for you.