# How to disable a touchscreen

Tags: 14.04

I have a Toshiba laptop with a touchscreen that is cracked and messed up. How do I disable my touch screen in Ubuntu 14.04.2?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run `xinput` command to determine what's your touchscreen's id is, and then make `xinput disable x` run on every boot, where x is the id number. Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/581334/295286

Comment: Thank you, but neither of you solutions worked. As soon as I touched the screen again it enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I have also seen that, run (xinput –list)
Identify touch screen from the list produced

Then run the following line to disable:
xinput –disable “Name Of Your Touch Screen”

Running this line will enable it:
xinput –enable “Name Of Your Touch Screen”

Answer (score 0):

this script works for me. my Hp Envy 360 touch screen cracked after an accident but the main screen works fine (so far)

```
\#!/bin/bash

OIFS=$IFS


\# note that the pen didnt show up until I mapped the standard one or clicked the screen. - [ this comment only relevant for digitiser pens.]
\# so need to do that first


list=$(xinput | grep $search | grep pointer)
echo "list $list"

\# extract the ids from the list, id's are needed and can change at the next login/boot
\# my Hp envy touchscreen is ELAN0732:00 which is the first column  of # "xinput" .
 Change it to yours here

device_id=$(echo "$list" | sed -n 's/.*ELAN0732:00.*id=\ 
([0-9]*\).*/\1/p')


for i in $device_id
do
echo "id is $i"
xinput disable $i 
done
```

save the script, make it executable, super key, type start , select startup applications, select add, give it a name, command is -

```
bash "/yourpath/yourscriptname.sh"
```